# How does get_comment_permalink in Django's comments framework work?

Tags: python, django, django-comments

I don't really understand [`get_comment_permalink`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/#linking-to-comments) in Django's comments framework.

I created a few comments for my class `Order` using Django's comments, by default it shows a url of something like `/comments/cr/18/1/#c1` and that url never exists.

I looked at the comment's `urls.py` and it has a line that says

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^cr/(\d+)/(.+)/$', 'django.contrib.contenttypes.views.shortcut', name='comments-url-redirect'),
)
```

The `views.py` which has the `shortcut` method is

```
from django import http
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site, get_current_site
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

def shortcut(request, content_type_id, object_id):
    """
    Redirect to an object's page based on a content-type ID and an object ID.
    """
    # Look up the object, making sure it's got a get_absolute_url() function.
    try:
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(pk=content_type_id)
        if not content_type.model_class():
            raise http.Http404(_(u"Content type %(ct_id)s object has no associated model") %
                               {'ct_id': content_type_id})
        obj = content_type.get_object_for_this_type(pk=object_id)
    except (ObjectDoesNotExist, ValueError):
        raise http.Http404(_(u"Content type %(ct_id)s object %(obj_id)s doesn't exist") %
                           {'ct_id': content_type_id, 'obj_id': object_id})

    try:
        get_absolute_url = obj.get_absolute_url
    except AttributeError:
        raise http.Http404(_("%(ct_name)s objects don't have a get_absolute_url() method") %
                           {'ct_name': content_type.name})
    absurl = get_absolute_url()

    # Try to figure out the object's domain, so we can do a cross-site redirect
    # if necessary.

    # If the object actually defines a domain, we're done.
    if absurl.startswith('http://') or absurl.startswith('https://'):
        return http.HttpResponseRedirect(absurl)

    # Otherwise, we need to introspect the object's relationships for a
    # relation to the Site object
    object_domain = None

    if Site._meta.installed:
        opts = obj._meta

        # First, look for an many-to-many relationship to Site.
        for field in opts.many_to_many:
            if field.rel.to is Site:
                try:
                    # Caveat: In the case of multiple related Sites, this just
                    # selects the *first* one, which is arbitrary.
                    object_domain = getattr(obj, field.name).all()[0].domain
                except IndexError:
                    pass
                if object_domain is not None:
                    break

        # Next, look for a many-to-one relationship to Site.
        if object_domain is None:
            for field in obj._meta.fields:
                if field.rel and field.rel.to is Site:
                    try:
                        object_domain = getattr(obj, field.name).domain
                    except Site.DoesNotExist:
                        pass
                    if object_domain is not None:
                        break

    # Fall back to the current site (if possible).
    if object_domain is None:
        try:
            object_domain = get_current_site(request).domain
        except Site.DoesNotExist:
            pass

    # If all that malarkey found an object domain, use it. Otherwise, fall back
    # to whatever get_absolute_url() returned.
    if object_domain is not None:
        protocol = request.is_secure() and 'https' or 'http'
        return http.HttpResponseRedirect('%s://%s%s'
                                         % (protocol, object_domain, absurl))
    else:
        return http.HttpResponseRedirect(absurl)
```

and it's too complicated for me to understand.

When Django says permalink, I think about having a reference to a particular place on a page (usually a header). For example, the Django's comments framework documentation is link #1, and you can permalink the "Linking to Comments" section with link #2.

```
1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/
2. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/#linking-to-comments
```

So for the comments, shouldn't it be the same? Shouldn't the URL simply be a `#c1` or something without the `/comments/cr/18/1/...`? In fact I don't even know where Django got `18` and `1`... From the `shortcut` method, I understand that `18` is the `content_type_id` and `1` is the `object_id`, but how can I tell which class in `models.py` is which content type id and object id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So for the comments, shouldn't it be the same? Shouldn't the URL simply be a #c1 or something without the /comments/cr/18/1/...? In fact I don't even know where Django got 18 and 1... From the shortcut method, I understand that 18 is the content_type_id and 1 is the

18 is the content type id, and 1 is the object id. The shortcut view fetches the object from the database using these parameters and redirects to `modelobject.get_absolute_url()`.

**Define/fix get_absolute_url() method in your models**, this will repair `django.contrib.contenttypes.views.shortcut`.

That said, it is expected by Django that the url of the model object displays the list of comments for this object. In that case, just add `<a name="c{{ comment.id }}"></a>` in your single comment HTML.

Comment: Doesn't this seem to violate DRY pinciple/loose coupling? I have defined `def get_absolute_url( self ) : return "/doors/orders/{pk}/".format( pk = self.pk )` in my `models.py` and defined `r'^orders/(?P<pk>\d+)/$'` in `urls.py` inside my doors app (the full path would still be something like `/doors/orders/1/`). Is there a way to `reverse` or `reverse_lazy` this?

Comment: It is another question so I'll be brief, but, you are right ! You should just do something like this to get the url: `from django.core import urlresolvers; urlresolvers.reverse('doors_order_detail', args=[self.pk])`. Of course, this requires that you [name your order detail url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#id2) 'doors_order_detail' which is pretty standard in Django.

Answer (score 4):

The comments framework uses [Generic Relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) to link `Comment` objects to your database objects (`Order` model in your case). Generic relationships allow one object to maintain a relationship with another object without explicitly knowing about it's class. You can see the fields creating the generic relationship (content_type, object_pk, content_object) for comment here: [`django.contrib.comments.models`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/comments/models.py#L14)

Once a comment has been made and attached to an instance of a particular class (a single `Order` for example), we need a way to get a link to that particular comment (the permalink). To get a link to a comment, we need to know the URL of the object the comment has been made on (again, the particular `Order` in your case). This is what `get_comment_permalink` is doing - it constructs a URL to the object for which a comment has been left on and also attached an anchor link (the `#c1` part) to the URL so that the browser jumps to a particular comment on that page.

To do all this it has 3 steps:

- first figure out what type of object it's dealing with by looking up the generic relationship. This will leave us with a `Order` object
- Now it tries to get the absolute url [`get_absolute_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#get-absolute-url) of that object. This might be /order/my-order/
- It constructs that `http://mysite.com/' part of the URL by using the Sites framework
- It figures out the #c31 (anchor link to the comment) part of the url

Now we have a full http://mysite.com/order/my-order/c#31 that will bring us to the correct page and show the correct comment

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on the Generic Relations!